# groupby value_counts store in a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like -

```
city
a
f
m
m
m
d
```

I want to store this data into other data frame -

```
city       total
a           1
f           1
m           3
d           1
```

my code is -

```
df_city = df.groupby(['city'])['city'].count()
```

but not getting proper results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `groupby` is better if want avoid sorting `total` - add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter:

```
df_city = df.groupby('city')['city'].count().reset_index(name='total')
print (df_city)
  city  total
0    a      1
1    d      1
2    f      1
3    m      3
```

If use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) output is sorting, for `DataFrame` add [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df_city = df['city'].value_counts().rename_axis('city').reset_index(name="total")
print (df_city)
  city  total
0    m      3
1    d      1
2    f      1
3    a      1
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
df['city'].value_counts().to_frame(name="Total")
```

Comment: You can use `.to_frame()` for it. I updated my answer to your query

Comment: @PallaviVerma, Could you please check my answer once and lemme know if that helps you too?

Answer (score 1):

Develop from your codes

```
df.groupby('city').city.count().rename('total').reset_index()

Out[505]:
  city  total
0    a      1
1    d      1
2    f      1
3    m      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
df['total']=df.groupby('city').cumcount()+1
df.drop_duplicates('city',keep='last').reset_index(drop='True')
```

***To store this in a data frame use:***

```
df['total']=df.groupby('city').cumcount()+1
df1=df.drop_duplicates('city',keep='last').reset_index(drop='True')
df1
```

When we print `df` its value will be as follows:

```
   city total
0   a   1
1   f   1
2   m   3
3   d   1
```